# action - not calling execute() method

Tags: java, spring, struts2, return, tiles

I am getting crazy.. I am searching for my mistake since hours.

My form isn't going into the action. But I checked it 1000 times. Everything is spelled right.
I have no idea...
Please please help!

my beloved error msg:

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action
>   de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.CreatePubAction and result input
>
> type Status report
>
> message No result defined for action
>   de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.CreatePubAction and result input
>
> description The requested resource is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/7.0.42

Thats the jsp. in Folder jsp called createPublication.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


<title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Fügen Sie eine neue Publikation hinzu</h3>
    <s:form action="createPubAction">
        <s:textfield key="publication.title" />
        <%-- <s:textfield key="publication.author" /> --%>
        <s:textfield key="publication.publisher" />
        <s:textfield key="publication.publishment" />
        <s:textfield key="publication.isbn" />
        <s:textfield key="publication.stock" />
        <s:if test="%{publicationtypes.isEmpty()}">
            keine Publikationstypen
        </s:if>
        <s:else>
            <s:select Listkey="publication.type" list="publicationtypes.{type}" />
        </s:else>

        <s:if test="%{keywords.isEmpty()}">
            keine Schlagwörter
        </s:if>
        <s:else>
        <s:checkboxlist key="publication.keyword" label="Schlagworte"
            name="keywordsL1" list="keywords.{name}" />
        </s:else> 
        <s:submit label="save" value="Speichern" />
    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Struts.xml
newPublication is calling the Page where I need to enter the needed Informations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<!-- mapping of global-results and global-exceptions -->

<struts>
    <constant name="struts.enable.DynamicMethodInvocation" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />

    <package name="default" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>

        <default-action-ref name="Start" />

        <action name="Start"     class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.StartAction">
            <result type="tiles" name="success">main</result>
        </action>

        <action name="newPublication"
            class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.NewPublication">
            <result type="tiles" name="success">createPublication</result>
        </action>

        <action name="createPubAction"
            class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.CreatePubAction">
            <result type="tiles" name="success">catalog</result>
        </action>


        <action name="catalogAction"
            class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.navi.CatalogAction">
            <result type="tiles" name="success">catalog</result>
        </action>

    </package>
</struts>
```

The Tiles file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
        "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">

    <tiles-definitions>
        <definition name="main" template="/jsp/main.jsp">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Dashboard"/>
            <put-attribute name="menu" value="/jsp/menu.jsp"/>
            <put-attribute name="header" value="/jsp/header.jsp"/>
            <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/start.jsp"/>
        </definition>

        <definition name="dashboard" extends="main">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Dashboard"/>
            <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/start.jsp"/>
        </definition>

        <definition name="rental" extends="main">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Verleihvorgänge"/>
            <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/rental.jsp"/>
        </definition>

        <definition name="catalog" extends="main">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Katalog"/>
            <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/catalog.jsp"/>
        </definition>

        <definition name="createPublication" extends="main">
            <put-attribute name="title" value="Neue Publikation erstellen"/>
            <put-attribute name="content" value="/jsp/createPublication.jsp"/>
        </definition>
    </tiles-definitions>
```

and last but not least the action:

```
package de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

import de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.model.Publication;
import de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.service.IPublicationService;

public class CreatePubAction extends ActionSupport {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Publication publication;
    private IPublicationService publicationService;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        try{
            publicationService.savePublication(publication);
            return SUCCESS;
        } catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ERROR;
        }
    }

    public Publication getPublication() {
        return publication;
    }

    public void setPublication(Publication publication) {
        this.publication = publication;
    }

    public IPublicationService getPublicationService() {
        return publicationService;
    }

    public void setPublicationService(IPublicationService publicationService) {
        this.publicationService = publicationService;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is result type in your createPubAction of struts.xml file? Where it points to?

Comment: <result type="tiles" name="success">catalog</result>
and this is an jsp-page. which is working if i call it from the navigation

Comment: its not. its the "name" which i am calling in the struts.xml ... and the name is spelled small and then in the classpath the name is spelled big ;)

Comment: Just saw it, deleted comment. Other question: The others work, right? It's just that createPubAction one that's giving you hell?

Comment: yes :( just this single stupid one

Comment: You don't have an input result for the action.

Comment: Add struts filter in web.xml

Comment: It's returning result input and for input nothing is defined, It's having validation error. Try to define a input as well like success.

Answer (score 0):

Do you ever see a stacktrace in the logs?

I venture to guess that your ERROR response is being called and you do not have it mapped.  Can you try explicitly defining an ERROR result in your tiles configuration?

My initial gut feeling (from having dealt with a very similar issue) was that one of your JSP files is either misspelled in the tiles config or not included in the web application.  I would double check that.

Answer (score 0):

```
<action name="createPubAction"
            class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.CreatePubAction">
            <result type="tiles" name="success">catalog</result>
        </action>
```

You only have `success` defined. The error says, that the action is returning `input` result and as you can see above, there's no definition on what to do, if `input` result is encountered.

A quick fix can be :

```
<action name="createPubAction"
            class="de.nordakademie.librarymgmt.action.CreatePubAction">
            <result type="tiles" name="success">catalog</result>
            <result type="tiles" name="input">catalog</result>
        </action>
```